# Is something wrong with my cluster settings

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

Recently I setup an 8 node Hadoop and Spark cluster using Ambari on Microsoft Azure Platform. Each of the nodes (Standard DS2 v2 (2 cores, 7 GB memory)) in the cluster has the following standard configuration.

```
Memory : 7GB 

HDD : 1TB 

CPU : 2 cores 

OS : Ubuntu 14.04
```

I am trying to run some benchmarks using the [Intel HiBench](https://github.com/intel-hadoop/HiBench) suite but the time it takes to execute the wordcount workload takes too much to me. So I am not sure if this has something to do with my configuration or this is normal.

My data and job configurations specified in conf/hibench.conf are presented below.

```
Data : 1TB (bigdata)

Mapper number in hadoop, partition number in Spark

hibench.default.map.parallelism         8

# Reducer nubmer in hadoop, shuffle partition number in Spark

hibench.default.shuffle.parallelism     4
```

The time it took Spark to run the wordcount workload or job is 8 hours 22 minutes. Is this normal or is there something wrong with my cluster configuration.

More information about the benchmark tool I am using can be obtained from `https://github.com/intel-hadoop/HiBench.`

Comment: What is Spark word count code can you update that .

Comment: The SparkWord Count code is included in the Intel-HiBench suite. So it must be a well written one. More information about the benchmarking tool can be obtained https://github.com/intel-hadoop/HiBench.